# IPv6 as public IP

Tags: networking, server

I added a static IPv6 public IP address to my Ubuntu Virtual Machine.
And routed it in my server, but can't get it to work.

When I'm on the server, and go to the local IPv4 or IPv6 address, I get the Webserver Nginx page.

But when I'm going to the Public IPv6, it doesn't work out:

> Eth0: inet6 addr: 2a00:***:**::**f/48 Scope Global

I also added an AAAA-record, referring to the IPv6-address. But still no clue.

Am I missing something out in the configuration of Ubuntu?

Reason for doing this: IPv4's aren't free, IPv6's are at my datacenter.

Comment: How do you get your IPv6? Do IPv6 work? How do `ip -6 route` look look? How do `ip -6 addr` look like? How is IPv6 set up in the host? How do you route through your host? You should have a /64 net for your virtual machine, and host. Use the /48 net and divide it in /64 nets. LAN should never have nothing but /64 nets.